# How to find all possible xy=k passing through integer points in n*n square

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, curves, integers

I want to find all possible xy=n passing through integer points such that 1 ≤ x ≤ n, 1 ≤y ≤ n

[image]

For ex.

Suppose n=4, then

Xy= 12 is a valid solution (it passes through (3, 4), which are both integer)

Xy=14 is not a solution, because there is no integer (a, b), where 1 ≤ a, b ≤ 4 such that ab=14.
,

Comment: Please make clear which is the question and which are the essential conditions in the question. The integer $14$ (and any other positive integer) is a solution, because $x=1$, $y=n$ verifies the given conditions. Then the list of the tags is a little exaggerated. There is no abstract algebra involved above, there are no elliptic curves involved. I also do not see any sequence / series. One more word about the format. Please use mathjax to format mathematical symbols, examples are here for instance: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: This may be equivalent to the *Erdos multiplication table problem*, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31663/distinct-numbers-in-multiplication-table

Comment: This problem is not trivial, as Gerry Myerson's link shows. See also [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Tenenbaum%E2%80%93Ford_constant) and [A027424](https://oeis.org/A027424) on oeis.